# Как сохранить scroll position vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Всем привет. К примеру есть страницы page1 и page2. На странице page1 есть ссылка которая введет на страницу page2, она находится на расстояние 1000px от топа. А на странице page2 есть кнопка, которая возвращает пользователя на страницу page1. Как после того как мы нажимаем на кнопку на странице page2 для перехода на страницу page1 вернуть нас на то же самое расстояние от топа?

Читал про функцию scrollBehavior, но откуда vue будет знать, откуда и на какой странице сохранять scroll position?

Comment: scroll position сохраняется если использовать `history.back`, но в контексте `vue`, вместо `router-link` на `page2` - повесьте обработчик события `click` на ссылку и вызовите `this.$router.back()`

Comment: Сделал... На странице `page2`, чтобы вернуться на страницу `page1` вызываю метод `historyBack` в котором вызываю `this.$router.back()`

Comment: Но scroll position не сохраняется

Comment: я подразумеваю, что у Вас какие-то динамические данные на `page1`, которые рендерятся через `v-for`?

Comment: Да, все правильно

Comment: данные статические? в смысле они постоянно приходят одни и те же с сервера или нет?

Comment: Одни и те же, вызывается метод, который выводит из бд записи, но они могут соответственно пополняться в бд

Comment: хорошо, дайте пару минут на написание ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как у Вас на `page1` данные приходят с сервера и рендерятся каждый раз в `v-for`, то очевидно, что `scroll position` запоминаться не будет. Могу предложить Вам такой метод решения данной проблемы - создать сервис, который будет кешировать эти данные, чтобы каждый раз, переходя на `page1`, не обращаться к БД, он должен быть синглтоном:

```
// cache.service.js

export class CacheService {
    constructor() {
        this.cache = {};
    }

    mutateCache(key, value) {
        this.cache = {
            ...this.cache,
            [key]: value
        };
    }

    getCache() {
        return this.cache;
    }
}
```

Создаем "псевдо dependency injection", то есть инжектор, который будет инициализировать нужные нам сервисы только при первом доступе, эдакой `lazy map`:

```
// di.js

import { CacheService } from './cache.service';

const injector = new WeakMap();

injector.set(CacheService, {
    value: null,
    factory: () => new CacheService()
});

export function getDependency(ctor) {
    const entry = injector.get(ctor);

    if (entry.factory) {
        const factory = entry.factory;
        entry.factory = null;
        entry.value = factory();
    }

    return entry.value;
}
```

В компоненте `page1` нам достаточно 1 раз получить данные с сервера и закешировать их:

```
<script>
import { getDependency } from './path-to/di.js';
import { CacheService } from './path-to/cache-service.js';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            someData: []
        };
    },

    mounted() {
        const service = getDependency(CacheService);
        const cache = service.getCache();

        if (!cache.someData) {
            makeSomeApiCall().then((someData) => {
                this.$data.someData = someData;

                service.mutateCache('someData', this.$data.someData);
            });
        } else {
            this.$data.someData = cache.someData;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Вариант с использованием `vuex`:

```
yarn add vue@3.0.1
```

Создаем папку `store` и подключаем плагин:

```
// store/index.js

import Vuex, { Store } from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Store({
    state: {
        someData: []
    },

    mutations: {
        setData(state, { someData }) {
            state.someData = someData;
        }
    }
});
```

Передаем `store` параметром в конструктор `Vue` при создании приложения:

```
import { store } from './path-to/store';

new Vue({
    ...,
    ...,
    store,
    render: (h) => ....
}).$mount('#app');
```

Теперь можем напрямую использовать в компоненте через свойство `$store`:

```
<template>
    <div class="page-1">
        <div v-for="data in someData">{{ data }}</div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from './path-to/store';

export default {
    computed: {
        someData: () => this.$store.state.someData
    },

    mounted() {
        if (this.$store.state.someData.length > 0) {
            return;
        }

        makeSomeApiCall().then((someData) => {
            this.$store.commit('setData', { someData });
        });
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: А как-то по другому можно решить мою проблему?

Comment: @Евгений к сожалению, нет, самый последний вариант `SSR` (`nuxt.js`)

Comment: @overthesanity если я правильно понимаю, автор подразумевал использование роутера, в котором есть встроенный параметр `scrollBehavior`.